# dropdown using <li> bootstrap sub menu doesn't opens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, html-lists, submenu

```
<li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Utilitas<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="user.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Master User</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ms_pejabat.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Master Penanda Tangan</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="tipe.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Master Tipe & NJKB</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="chating.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Chat Room</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="usersms.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Super User SMS Gateway</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="runningtext.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Running Text</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="upload.php?bagian=list&hal=1">Upload Datar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: what you tried yet? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Considering you have tagged Bootstrap 4, your syntax is wrong. `data-bs-toggle` is a B5 syntax, not B4. For B4, use `data-toggle` only. Otherwise your code looks fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code was completely working fine. kindly check you inserted bootstrap script before your closing body tag.

**note:** based on your version.